# Let $f\in L[a,b]$ assume for any sub interval $I \in [a,b]$ we have $\int_If\ge \lvert I\rvert$ ,show that $f\ge1$ $a.e$ on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is as title

I know there is a same problem on [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050484/showing-f-ge1-a-e-on-a-b), but I have some problems of the answers below.

I also started with contradiction, to assume there exist measure of $m\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)<1\}>0$

Anyone has better idea on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that $|I| = mI$, the length of the interval.

Note the result that if $\int_{I} \phi \ge 0$ for all intervals, then $\phi(x) \ge 0 $ ae. $x$.

Now note that $\int_I 1 = |I|$ so we can write the above as $\int_I f \ge \int_I 1$ or, equivalently, $\int_I (f-1) \ge 0$.

Let $\phi(x) = f(x) -1$. Then we have $\int_I \phi \ge 0$ for all intervals
$I$, and hence $\phi(x) \ge 0 $ for ae. $x$. Hence $f(x) \ge 1$ for ae. $x$.

**Note**:

To see the above, let $g(t) = \int_{[a,t]} \phi$, then $g$ is non decreasing since
$g(t+h) = g(t) + \int_{[t,t+h]} \phi$. Since $g'(x) = \phi(x)$ for ae. $x$,
we have the desired result.

Comment: I don't get it. What is this related to the problem??

Comment: It is a solution to the problem. Note that $\int_{[d,e]} 1 = e-d$, the length of the interval, so $\int_I f \ge |I|$ is equivalent to $\int_I (f-1) \ge 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I still confuse

Comment: You need to describe what is confusing. Do you understand the first statement?

Comment: I have added more detail, if you have specific questions I can answer them.

Comment: I think I got it now. Since we have $\int_If\gt \lvert I \rvert$,=> $\int_If\gt \int_I1$ => $\int_If- \int_I1\ge0$ =>$\int_If-1\ge0$=>$f-1\ge0$ $a.e$ Is that right?

Comment: That is correct (except $> \to \ge$).

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Comment: If the Lebesgue differentiation theorem can be used, we can just argue that $x\in [a,b),$ we have

$$\frac{1}{h} \int_x^{x+h} f \ge \frac{1}{h}\cdot h = 1$$

for small $h>0.$ The LDT says the limit of the left side as $h\to 0^+$ equals $f(x)$ for a.e. $x.$ Therefore $f(x)\ge 1$ a.e.

Comment: @zhw.: Well, my goal wasn't a short proof, it was to connect the problem with a well known result ($\int_I \phi \ge 0$ implies $\phi \ge 0$ ae.). Perhaps a direct proof such as yours would have been clearer.